# LinkedIn share plugin and open graph description missing and two images

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a LinkedIn share plugin on my website and basic open graph tags: title, type, URL, description, image (which are working just fine according to Facebook debugger).

I have two problems:

1) When I share in LinkedIn the preview popup shows title and description just as it should. However when I see the actual post, the description text is missing, only title is shown. Why is that?

2) The LinkedIn preview popup shows two images, from which the user can choose from. I have defined an open graph image tag and that is the image I want to use in my posts. Now the preview shows that image and also another image from my page (that should not be used when sharing). Can I do something that the plugin uses only the image defined by the open graph tag?

Answer (score 0):

For LinkedIn, you can use the `og:image` tag, or you can use the `og:description` tag, but you cannot have both.  By using the image tag, you disable the use of the description tag.  I spent a week with [LinkedIn Support](https://www.revoltlib.com/linkedin-social-share-url-broken-ticket.html) struggling to get this to work, and that is the problem.

Naturally, since many apps want to use your `og:` tags, (search engines, API's, etc.), you shouldn't tailor these tags to what LinkedIn wants.  So, naturally, you'll be likely to opt with using the `og:image` tags.

I tested the above hypothesis...

- [Wikipedia](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikipedia.org%2F): `og:description`, but no `og:image`.  Description shows!
- [GitHub](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.github.com%2F): Both `og:description` and `og:image`.  But no description shows!

Maybe one day they'll fix this, but for now, it seems to be all we have for the LinkedIn share API.